# Use Curl to securely access data on another server

Tags: php, curl

I want to validate license in my plugin.

User on his website enters token (provided by me) and I want to validate this by contacting my server using curl.

For example,

Code in plugin:

```
function curl_url( $url ) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    $cr = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $cr;
}

$confirm = 'https://my-website.com/some_folder/some_file.php?token=' . $token;

$response = json_decode( curl_url( $confirm ) );
```

Code on my website in some_file.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['token'])){
    validate();  

}

function validate(){
    $token= $_GET['token'];
    //check if valid, provide response...
}
```

MY questions:

1. How good or bad approach is this, what do you advise to me?
2. What is some advanced user sees code in my plugin and then uses this url for some malicious attacks?

   https://my-website.com/some_folder/some_file.php

Comment: Instead of just transfering the token as plaintext you may use some encryption at both the end using a shared key.. So even if someone get access to the token verification URL, they need to know the secret key to send an ACCEPTABLE request. There are lot of such codes you will get on stackoverflow or just search on google.

Comment: Well, this looks like fetching data from an API and is fine. From a security standpoint, you can make tokens have a limited lifetime so that attackers can't replay tokens if they catch hold of any token somehow.

Comment: I'd say the main problem is the fact that users can see your code, so there is nothing prohibits them just remove this token validation and use your plugin without license

Comment: You will also need to decide how much you want to potentially aggravate developers in regards to storage of the fact that the license is valid. Many paid plugins will validate in order to activate, but then won't revalidate until the update system kicks in. This allows developers to make backup development copies of the site with all plugins running, just some not being able to update. Many of my paid plugins also have a portal where I can deactivate installs so that I can activate them elsewhere, for instance if a domain changes.

Comment: Yes, really bad, if you are shipping this code with a software / plugin. But okay, if the code resides on your server / project / website.

Comment: Also you can create a checksum of your file and send it along and at the validating end, make sure that a predefined checksum matches. This way, if someone alters your code, the checksum will fail.

Comment: @IłyaBursov - Yes, that true of course, forgot to mention, but this doesnt matter to me, most of the buyers are fair users who will validate their license, not striping code..

Comment: @ChrisHaas - I also have this idea in mind, plugin should check license on each run, and users will have member area on my website where they can possibly deactivate domain certain number or times or time wise (or similar).

Comment: "on each run" - depending on where this plugin lives (WordPress, Drupal, etc.) that might be a potential performance issue, and there's also a chance that it fails which could break someone's site, so be careful of that, too.

Comment: @Toniq, can you clarify where your plugin is actually going to live? I ask because if this were, for instance a WordPress plugin, there's system-specific code for performing [remote HTTP requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/). For other systems there's probably similar things, too. It is a small thing, but it can make testing easier and would probably be more cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently if I try to reach my server from another domain, I dont get
> any errors and request works so I ma not sure why I need
> CURLOPT_CAINFO. – Toniq

Compare the results between the two domains.

curl_getinfo is very useful.

```
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT
echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

Other useful curl info.

```
CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT
CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH the HTTP authentication method(s) to use.
CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES
CURLINFO_CERTINFO true to output SSL certification information to STDERR on secure transfers
CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME
```

Options

```
CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default. 
CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS
CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD
CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY
CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE 
CURLOPT_CAPATH A directory that holds multiple CA certificates
CURLOPT_CAINFO The name of a file holding one or more certificates to verify the peer with. 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST 0 to not check the names. 1 should not be used. 2 to verify that a Common Name field 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  false to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS  true to verify the certificate's status. 
CURLOPT_CERTINFO true to output SSL certification information to STDERR on secure transfers. 
CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   true to force the use of a new connection instead of a cached one. 
CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN
CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN
CURLOPT_SSL_FALSESTART  true to enable TLS false start. 
CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES
CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST
CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD
CURLOPT_SSLKEY
CURLOPT_SSLENGINE
CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD
CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST
CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE
CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE
CURLOPT_USERNAME
CURLOPT_PASSWORD
CURLOPT_USERPWD [username]:[password]
CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER  Specifies the OAuth 2.0 access token. 

CURLOPT_VERBOSE
CURLOPT_STDERR  A file handle to output errors to instead of STDERR. 
$errno = curl_errno($ch)
$error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
```

You should be checking for errors.

```
CURLOPT_VERBOSE
CURLOPT_STDERR  A file handle to output errors to instead of STDERR. 
$errno = curl_errno($ch)
$error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
```

CURLError codes

```
CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_NOTFOUND (53)
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED (54)
CURLE_SSL_CERTPROBLEM (58)
CURLE_SSL_CIPHER (59)
CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (60)
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_INITFAILED (66)
CURLE_LOGIN_DENIED (67)
CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE (77)
CURLE_SSH (79)
CURLE_SSL_CRL_BADFILE (82)
CURLE_SSL_ISSUER_ERROR (83)
CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH (90)
CURLE_SSL_INVALIDCERTSTATUS (91)
CURLE_AUTH_ERROR (94)
CURLE_SSL_CLIENTCERT (98)
```

> Can you provide this header example? –  Toniq

Add header to curl:

```
$token = 'token';
$request = array();
$request[] = "X-Token: $token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

When received by the server:

```
Content-Length: 55098
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close
X-Token: token
```

The code for server to read header:

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $key=> $value) {
   $header[$key] = $value;
}
$token = $header['X-Token'];
```

It appears you may be in over your head.  You should have known this considering what you are trying to do.  This is the very easy part.  You still need to deal with the SSL (CURLOPT_CAINFO).

---

---

You probably need to specify the SSL certificate or the path to the CA. 
From PHP manual's `curl_setopt` page

> Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the
> CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with
> the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.

In the url script try this code to get the details of your request.
It should help you find the problem in your request. 
I've been using it for years and it has helped so many times.

I copied this code a PHP script, here is the script.
You could use this link as your curl URL.

[LINK to the code below](http://eatled.com/receiveheader.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
$decode = false;
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    if(strpos($value,'urlenc')){$decode = true;};
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
echo "\nBODY\n";
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
//if($decode){$body = urldecode($body);}
echo $body;

echo "\n\n\$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])\n";
echo urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "\n\nargv\n";
foreach($_SERVER['argv']as $key=>$value){
  echo "\n$key = " . urldecode($value) . "\n";
}
echo "\n\$_POST\n";
var_export($_POST);

echo "\n\$_GET\n";
var_export($_GET);

echo "\n\$_REQUEST\n";
var_export($_REQUEST);

echo "\n\$_FILES\n";
var_export($_FILES);
echo "\n\$_SERVER\n";
var_export($_SERVER);
exit;
```

Comment: Can you explain more in what circumstances would I use this?

Comment: When your curl request does not do what you expect it to do.   I replace the API URL with this link and it will show what has gone wrong.  BTW, you should not use a GET request as the token should be passed encrypted.  The token should be passed in the header and the header should be encrypted.

Comment: Can you provide this header example?

Comment: Token I am sending is just a random generated string stored in my database to validate license. I am not sure it needs encoding? If attacker can see my code, I dont see what harm can he do with this token.

Comment: The title of your post (Use Curl to securely access data) and this option (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);) indicates you wanted secure access.  If you do not necessarily what SSL then set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false.  And if access will only be from your customer's website you can also use the IP address in the validation.

Comment: Currently if I try to reach my server from another domain, I dont get any errors and request works so I ma not sure why I need CURLOPT_CAINFO.

Comment: The other domain probably has the certificates.  There are a lot of things that can go wrong.  I'll add some troubleshooting methods to my answer.